# Search ArrayList for keywords and return location

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I am trying to write a method that search an ArrayList of a particular word and then prints the location of all of the occurrences of the word.

Here is what I have, it works fine until I enter the word  I want to search but then it prints nothing:

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class W7E2 {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        System.out.println("Please anter words: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String []w = sc.nextLine().split(" ");

        ArrayList<Words> word = new ArrayList<Words>();
        for(int i=0; i<w.length; i++) {
            word.add(new Words(w[i]));
        }
        System.out.println(word);

        System.out.println("Please enter the word you want to search: ");
        String search = sc.nextLine();


        for(Words ws: word) {
            if(ws.equals(search)) {
                System.out.println(ws.getLocation());
            }
        }

    }

    static class Words{
        private String wor;
        private static int number = -1;

        public Words(String wor) {
            this.wor = wor;
            number++;
        }
        public int getLocation() {
            return number;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return wor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Answer (score 2):

In your `if` statement to see if the `ArrayList` contains the word you have:

```
if(ws.equals(search)) {
    System.out.println(ws.getLocation());
}
```

But `ws` is a `Word` object and unless you override the `equals()` method, it will never equal the `String` object. You need to do something like:

```
if(ws.getwor().equals(search)) {
        System.out.println(ws.getLocation());
}
```

This is assuming that you create a get method for `wor`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides GBlodgett's answer,the `number` in class `Word` is static,so each `Word` instance will have a same number,you need to use a no-static variable to store the location

```
static class Words{
    private String wor;
    private static int number = -1;
    private int location;

    public Words(String wor) {
        this.wor = wor;
        number++;
        location = number;
    }
    public int getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public String toString() {
     return wor;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this :

```
for(Words ws: word) {
    if(ws.toString().equals(search)) { //to change
        System.out.println(ws.getLocation());
    }
}
```

ws is the object of Words class, you have to change it to toString()

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is instead of 
`ws.equals(search)` 
you need to add 
`ws.toString().equals(search)` 
as you return the word from the 
`toString()`
method in the `Words` Class.
So the code should look something like this,

```
  for(Words ws: word) {
            if(ws.toString().equals(search)) {
                System.out.println(ws.getLocation());
            }
        }
```